# Where should conditional action logic go?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, conditional-statements, standards

I am working on a project that uses ember. Conditional logic can be placed in the HTML template, the controller and where the function is define. I have an action that only needs to be fired when a global variable is true.

```
    <div {{action 'CallThisAction' on='click'}}>...</div>
```

In the .hbs I can do

```
{{#if global.x}}
   <div {{action 'CallThisAction' on='click'}}>...</div>
{{else}}
   <div>...</div>
{{/if}}
```

or in the function I can

```
CallThisAction(){
 if(global.x){
    //do something
   }
}
```

or I could add logic into the controller to prevent the CallThisAction from being called biased off the global.x. Controllers are also depreciated.

I could also pass as param:

```
CallThisAction(x){
 if(x){
    //do something
   }
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this? Ideally the solution here would be nice:[Feature Request](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1936)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template shouldn't use global variables. It's better to store such logic in your action:

```
actions: {
  CallThisAction(){
    if(!global || !global.x){
      return;
    }
    // do something
  }
}
```

Comment: I appreate the answer. I'm trying to better understand why, could you provide a reason?

Comment: Templates should store only required logic. It's view layer not controller layer. Templates and components should be as simple as possible. Your logic about what to do with action should be stored in controller. If you don't need to display different HTML in template when global.x isn't set, but you just want to fire action if global.x is set then it's better to move global.x check to controller and keep template simple.

Comment: Awesome! That makes sense.